# azure pipelines, dependency check (.net)

Tags: .net, azure, azure-pipelines

I want to use dependency check (https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck) with azure pipelines

I've already generated the result files with use ot the cmd step in azure pipeline with following script:

$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dependency-check/bin/dependency-check.bat --scan $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/packages/**/*.dll --noupdate --failOnCVSS "10" --format "ALL" --exclude $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dependency-check -log $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/verboselog.txt

as a result I get the following files:

- dependency-check-junit.xml
- dependency-check-report.csv
- dependency-check-report.html
- dependency-check-report.json
- dependency-check-report.xml

But I don't know how to display the results in the Test tab, does somebody have any ideas? (.net project)

Comment: Did you try below extension. How did it go? As Per Salmi pointed that using an extension is the easiest way. Or you will probably need to output your results in the a test.xml format file. And add A publish test results task to publish it to test tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OWASP Dependency Check extension from the Azure DevOps Marketplace, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dependency-check.dependencycheck.

To get the reports included in the test result view of the build you would need to use JUnit test framework as a part of your build, the configuration is described in the marketplace documentation.

Comment: But there is no other way? 
I really would like to avoid adding extensions and also we use NUnit not JUnit since this is  a .Net project.

Comment: The extension is probably the easiest way. JUnit will nog be used in the actual build of your code, only to process the Dependency Check output.